# Why does my pine script code not working?

Tags: pine-script

```
    //@version=4
strategy(title="daily crypto strategy", shorttitle="MyStrategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=2, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.07, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, currency = currency.USD)


/// ADX and DI

adxlen = input(14, "adx smoothing", minval=1, step=1)
dilen  = input(14, "DI length", minval=1, step=1)

dirmov(len) =>

    up        = change(high)
    down      = -change(low)
    truerange = rma(tr, len)
    plus      = fixnan(100 * rma(up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0, len) / truerange)
    minus     = fixnan(100 * rma(down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0, len) / truerange)

    [plus, minus]

adx(dilen, adxlen) => 

    [plus, minus] = dirmov(dilen)

    sum = plus + minus
    adx = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), adxlen)

    [adx, plus, minus]


//[adx, di+, d-]
[sig, up, down] = adx(dilen, adxlen)


// Function that calculates the DEMA
dema(series, length) =>
    if (length > 0)
        emaValue = ema(series, length)
        2 * emaValue - ema(emaValue, length)
    else
        na

/// RSİ

rsilen = input(14, "rsi length", minval=1, step=1)
uplimit = input(70, "up limit", minval=1, step=1)
downlimit = input(30, "down limit", minval=1, step=1)

//rsi
rsival = rsi(close, rsilen)
rsismooth1 = dema(rsival, 5)
rsismooth2 = dema(rsival, 10)


/// CHAIKIN

fast = input(3, "fast length", minval=1, step=1)
slow = input(14, "slow length", minval=1, step=1)

//chaikin osc

osc   = ema(accdist, fast) - ema(accdist, slow)
oscsmooth1 = dema(osc, 5)
oscsmooth2 = dema(osc, 10)

/// TP & SL

// sl_type    = input("%", options = ["%", "ATR", "Absolute"])

// sl_perc    = input(1,     title = "% SL",        type = input.float)
// atr_length = input(10,    title = "ATR Length")
// atr_mult   = input(1.2,   title = "ATR Mult",    type = input.float)
// sl_absol   = input(1,     title = "Absolute SL", type = input.float)

// // SL values
// sl_val = sl_type == "ATR"      ? atr_mult * atr(atr_length) : 
//          sl_type == "Absolute" ? sl_absol : 
//          close * sl_perc / 100

// // Configure trail stop level with input options (optional)
// longTrailPerc = input(title="Trail Long Loss (%)",
//      type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01

// shortTrailPerc = input(title="Trail Short Loss (%)",
//      type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01

//LONG

// // Determine trail stop loss prices
// longStopPrice = 0.0

// longStopPrice := if (strategy.position_size > 0)
//     stopValue = close * (1 - longTrailPerc)
//     max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
// else
//     0

long_tp1_inp = input(2, title='Long Take Profit 1 %', step=0.1)/100
long_tp1_qty = input(25, title="Long Take Profit 1 Qty", step=1)

long_tp2_inp = input(3, title='Long Take Profit 2 %', step=0.1)/100
long_tp2_qty = input(100, title="Long Take Profit 2 Qty", step=1)

long_sl_inp  = input(1, title='Long Stop Loss %', step=0.1)/100

long_take_level_1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_tp1_inp)
long_take_level_2 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_tp2_inp)
long_stop_level   = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - long_sl_inp)

//SHORT

// // Determine trailing short price
// shortStopPrice = 0.0

// shortStopPrice := if (strategy.position_size < 0)
//     stopValue = close * (1 + shortTrailPerc)
//     min(stopValue, shortStopPrice[1])
// else
//     999999

short_tp1_inp = input(2, title='Short Take Profit 1 %', step=0.1)/100
short_tp1_qty = input(25, title="Short Take Profit 1 Qty", step=1)

short_tp2_inp = input(3, title='Short Take Profit 2 %', step=0.1)/100
short_tp2_qty = input(100, title="Short Take Profit 2 Qty", step=1)

short_sl_inp  = input(1, title='Short Stop Loss %', step=0.1)/100

short_take_level_1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - short_tp1_inp)
short_take_level_2 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - short_tp2_inp)
short_stop_level   = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + short_sl_inp)


/// Strategy

//RSI overbought,oversold
ifdownlimit = rsival < downlimit ? true : crossover(rsival, downlimit) ? true : false
ifuplimit   = rsival > uplimit ? true : crossunder(rsival, uplimit) ? true : false

//CHAININ long,short
ifosclong   = crossover(osc, 0) ? true : oscsmooth1 > oscsmooth1[1] ? true : false
ifoscshort  = crossunder(osc, 0) ? true : oscsmooth1 < oscsmooth1[1]? true : false

//LONG               //rsi - dmi - chaikin strategy long entry
entry_long         = (ifdownlimit and crossunder(down, sig) and ifosclong) or (ifdownlimit and rsismooth1 > rsismooth1[1]) or (crossover(rsival, 50) and ifosclong)
entry_price_long   = valuewhen(entry_long,close,0)

exit_long          = close <= long_stop_level

//SHORT              //rsi - dmi - chaikin strategy short entry
entry_short        = (ifuplimit and crossunder(up, sig) and ifoscshort) or (ifuplimit and rsismooth1 < rsismooth1[1]) or (crossunder(rsival, 50) and ifoscshort)
entry_price_short  = valuewhen(entry_short,close,0)

exit_short         = close >= short_stop_level


///// BACKTEST PERIOD ///////
testStartYear      = input(2018, "Backtest Start Year")
testStartMonth     = input(1, "Backtest Start Month")
testStartDay       = input(1, "Backtest Start Day")
testPeriodStart    = timestamp(testStartYear, testStartMonth, testStartDay, 0, 0)

testStopYear       = input(2020, "Backtest Stop Year")
testStopMonth      = input(12, "Backtest Stop Month")
testStopDay        = input(31, "Backtest Stop Day")
testPeriodStop     = timestamp(testStopYear, testStopMonth, testStopDay, 0, 0)

testPeriod() =>
    time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? true : false

if testPeriod()
    if strategy.position_size == 0 or strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.entry("long", true, when = entry_long, comment="INSERT ENTER LONG COMMENT")
        strategy.exit("TP1", "long", qty_percent=long_tp1_qty, limit=long_take_level_1)
        strategy.exit("TP2", "long", qty_percent=long_tp2_qty, limit=long_take_level_2, comment = 'INSERT EXIT LONG COMMENT')
        strategy.close("long", when=exit_long, comment = "INSERT EXIT LONG COMMENT")
    
    if strategy.position_size == 0 or strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.entry("short", false, when = entry_short, comment="INSERT ENTER SHORT COMMENT")
        strategy.exit("TP1","short", qty_percent=short_tp1_qty, limit=short_take_level_1)
        strategy.exit("TP2","short", qty_percent=short_tp2_qty, limit=short_take_level_2, comment = "INSERT EXIT SHORT COMMENT")
        strategy.close("short", when=exit_short, comment = "INSERT EXIT SHORT COMMENT")


// LONG POSITION
plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? long_take_level_1 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green, linewidth=1, title="1st Long Take Profit")
plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? long_take_level_2 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green, linewidth=1, title="2nd Long Take Profit")
plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? long_stop_level : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title="Long Stop Loss")

// SHORT POSITION
plot(strategy.position_size < 0 ? short_take_level_1 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green, linewidth=1, title="1st Short Take Profit")
plot(strategy.position_size < 0 ? short_take_level_2 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green, linewidth=1, title="2nd Short Take Profit")
plot(strategy.position_size < 0 ? short_stop_level : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title="Long Stop Loss")
```

My pine script code is not working properly, it misses alarms.  and condition does not work.  looks at both conditions at the same time.  I'm waiting for it to happen in order.
I don't want both conditions to happen at the same time. Most of the time, conditions don't happen at the same time. what I want to do is wait for the other code when a condition is met and then enter the position.

Comment: You should post the code you have in order for the community to help you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I updated my question, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="daily crypto strategy", shorttitle="MyStrategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=2, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.07, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, currency = currency.USD)


/// ADX and DI

adxlen = input(14, "adx smoothing", minval=1, step=1)
dilen  = input(14, "DI length", minval=1, step=1)

dirmov(len) =>

    up        = change(high)
    down      = -change(low)
    truerange = rma(tr, len)
    plus      = fixnan(100 * rma(up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0, len) / truerange)
    minus     = fixnan(100 * rma(down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0, len) / truerange)

    [plus, minus]

adx(dilen, adxlen) => 

    [plus, minus] = dirmov(dilen)

    sum = plus + minus
    adx = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), adxlen)

    [adx, plus, minus]


//[adx, di+, d-]
[sig, up, down] = adx(dilen, adxlen)


// Function that calculates the DEMA
dema(series, length) =>
    if (length > 0)
        emaValue = ema(series, length)
        2 * emaValue - ema(emaValue, length)
    else
        na

/// RSİ

rsilen = input(14, "rsi length", minval=1, step=1)
uplimit = input(70, "up limit", minval=1, step=1)
downlimit = input(30, "down limit", minval=1, step=1)

//rsi
rsival = rsi(close, rsilen)
rsismooth1 = dema(rsival, 5)
rsismooth2 = dema(rsival, 10)


/// CHAIKIN

fast = input(3, "fast length", minval=1, step=1)
slow = input(14, "slow length", minval=1, step=1)

//chaikin osc

osc   = ema(accdist, fast) - ema(accdist, slow)
oscsmooth1 = dema(osc, 5)
oscsmooth2 = dema(osc, 10)

/// TP & SL

// sl_type    = input("%", options = ["%", "ATR", "Absolute"])

// sl_perc    = input(1,     title = "% SL",        type = input.float)
// atr_length = input(10,    title = "ATR Length")
// atr_mult   = input(1.2,   title = "ATR Mult",    type = input.float)
// sl_absol   = input(1,     title = "Absolute SL", type = input.float)

// // SL values
// sl_val = sl_type == "ATR"      ? atr_mult * atr(atr_length) : 
//          sl_type == "Absolute" ? sl_absol : 
//          close * sl_perc / 100

// // Configure trail stop level with input options (optional)
// longTrailPerc = input(title="Trail Long Loss (%)",
//      type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01

// shortTrailPerc = input(title="Trail Short Loss (%)",
//      type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01

//LONG

// // Determine trail stop loss prices
// longStopPrice = 0.0

// longStopPrice := if (strategy.position_size > 0)
//     stopValue = close * (1 - longTrailPerc)
//     max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
// else
//     0

long_tp1_inp = input(2, title='Long Take Profit 1 %', step=0.1)/100
long_tp1_qty = input(25, title="Long Take Profit 1 Qty", step=1)

long_tp2_inp = input(3, title='Long Take Profit 2 %', step=0.1)/100
long_tp2_qty = input(100, title="Long Take Profit 2 Qty", step=1)

long_sl_inp  = input(1, title='Long Stop Loss %', step=0.1)/100

long_take_level_1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_tp1_inp)
long_take_level_2 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_tp2_inp)
long_stop_level   = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - long_sl_inp)

//SHORT

// // Determine trailing short price
// shortStopPrice = 0.0

// shortStopPrice := if (strategy.position_size < 0)
//     stopValue = close * (1 + shortTrailPerc)
//     min(stopValue, shortStopPrice[1])
// else
//     999999

short_tp1_inp = input(2, title='Short Take Profit 1 %', step=0.1)/100
short_tp1_qty = input(25, title="Short Take Profit 1 Qty", step=1)

short_tp2_inp = input(3, title='Short Take Profit 2 %', step=0.1)/100
short_tp2_qty = input(100, title="Short Take Profit 2 Qty", step=1)

short_sl_inp  = input(1, title='Short Stop Loss %', step=0.1)/100

short_take_level_1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - short_tp1_inp)
short_take_level_2 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - short_tp2_inp)
short_stop_level   = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + short_sl_inp)


/// Strategy

//RSI overbought,oversold
co = crossover(rsival, downlimit)
cu = crossover(rsival, uplimit)

ifdownlimit = rsival < downlimit ? true : co ? true : false
ifuplimit   = rsival > uplimit ? true : cu ? true : false

//CHAININ long,short
ifosclong   = crossover(osc, 0) ? true : oscsmooth1 > oscsmooth1[1] ? true : false
ifoscshort  = crossunder(osc, 0) ? true : oscsmooth1 < oscsmooth1[1]? true : false

//LONG               //rsi - dmi - chaikin strategy long entry
entry_long         = (ifdownlimit and crossunder(down, sig) and ifosclong) or (ifdownlimit and rsismooth1 > rsismooth1[1]) or (crossover(rsival, 50) and ifosclong)
entry_price_long   = valuewhen(entry_long,close,0)

exit_long          = close <= long_stop_level

//SHORT              //rsi - dmi - chaikin strategy short entry
entry_short        = (ifuplimit and crossunder(up, sig) and ifoscshort) or (ifuplimit and rsismooth1 < rsismooth1[1]) or (crossunder(rsival, 50) and ifoscshort)
entry_price_short  = valuewhen(entry_short,close,0)

exit_short         = close >= short_stop_level


///// BACKTEST PERIOD ///////
testStartYear      = input(2018, "Backtest Start Year")
testStartMonth     = input(1, "Backtest Start Month")
testStartDay       = input(1, "Backtest Start Day")
testPeriodStart    = timestamp(testStartYear, testStartMonth, testStartDay, 0, 0)

testStopYear       = input(2020, "Backtest Stop Year")
testStopMonth      = input(12, "Backtest Stop Month")
testStopDay        = input(31, "Backtest Stop Day")
testPeriodStop     = timestamp(testStopYear, testStopMonth, testStopDay, 0, 0)

testPeriod() =>
    time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? true : false

if testPeriod()
    if strategy.position_size == 0 or strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.entry("long", true, when = entry_long, comment="L_in")
        strategy.exit("TP1", "long", qty_percent=long_tp1_qty, limit=long_take_level_1)
        strategy.exit("TP2", "long", qty_percent=long_tp2_qty, limit=long_take_level_2, comment = 'L_out')
        strategy.close("long", when=exit_long, comment = "L_out")
    
    if strategy.position_size == 0 or strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.entry("short", false, when = entry_short, comment="S_in")
        strategy.exit("TP1","short", qty_percent=short_tp1_qty, limit=short_take_level_1)
        strategy.exit("TP2","short", qty_percent=short_tp2_qty, limit=short_take_level_2, comment = "S_out")
        strategy.close("short", when=exit_short, comment = "S_out")


// LONG POSITION
plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? long_take_level_1 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green, linewidth=1, title="1st Long Take Profit")
plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? long_take_level_2 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green, linewidth=1, title="2nd Long Take Profit")
plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? long_stop_level : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title="Long Stop Loss")

// SHORT POSITION
plot(strategy.position_size < 0 ? short_take_level_1 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green, linewidth=1, title="1st Short Take Profit")
plot(strategy.position_size < 0 ? short_take_level_2 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green, linewidth=1, title="2nd Short Take Profit")
plot(strategy.position_size < 0 ? short_stop_level : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title="Long Stop Loss")
```